# How about using js2py to call or get python context

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I could use js2py to execute js code and get js context. Now i want to get python Object and Context data in js code.
so, i tryed to search github and google, but useless  :(
this makes me depressed, thx for your answer :)

python get js object and context,
temp.js is:

```
var db_user_name = ''
var db_password = ''
var port = ''
var host = ''
var service_name = ''

if(1 < 2){
    db_password = 'aa'
    db_user_name = 'bb'
    host = 'localhost'
    port = '8888'
    service_name = 'orcl'
}
```

python code:

```
import js2py
js_file = js2py.run_file(r'D:.....\temp.js')
print(js_file[1].db_user_name)
print(js_file[1].db_password)
print(js_file[1].host)
print(js_file[1].port)
print(js_file[1].service_name)
```

but now, how about using js2py to call or get python context?

Due to the need , i can't let python or js access each other in a file.
temp.js is configuration files, some complex process by python, i need the result to use in configuration files--such as temp.js

Comment: i want to get python object or context in js

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a sample:

```js
gen_guid="""
function createGuid() {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
}
var guid1 = createGuid() + createGuid() + "-" + createGuid() + "-" + createGuid() + createGuid() + "-" + createGuid() + createGuid() + createGuid();

"""
    context = js2py.EvalJs()
    context.execute(gen_guid)
    guid=context.guid1 # trans  guid1  -->Python code
    print guid
```